# how to reload tableview's particular section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 56 sections in my tableview, and I am storing the section number which is currently selected in an integer variable named "activeTimeSlot". How to use the below method to reload a section which is currently selected. I am doing it like

```
 [self.tblView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:activeTimeSlot] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

but I have observed that doing this way is calling the below datasource method of tableview for all the sections, i.e its reloading all the section.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

I am not sure how to use NSIndexSet and how to use NSIndexSet to reload more than 1 sections.

Comment: check my answer hope it will help you.

Comment: how did you figure out that is reloading all the sections?

Comment: because its calling numberOfRowsInSection method for all the sections@NicolaMiotto i mean 56 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I saw from your comments, you are checking the call of the method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

to figure out that it's reloading every section. But that method is called for all the sections for internal reasons probably. If you try to log which rows are actually realoaded, you'll see that everything is fine. put a

```
NSLog(@"Section %d", indexPath.section);
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and see that just rows from the selected section are reloaded.

PS: forgot to say: your solution was already correct.

Comment: yes its calling cellForRowAtIndexPath for that particular section only..I was too lazy that without checking I assumed that if its calling numberOfRows for all sections, than for sure it must be calling cellForRowAtIndexPath for all sections ..:) thanks anyways..)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to update multiple section then you can do this way.

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indetsetToUpdate = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc]init];

[indetsetToUpdate addIndex:previousSection]; // [indetsetToUpdate addIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#>] 
// You can add multiple indexes(sections) here.

[detailTableView reloadSections:indetsetToUpdate withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This is used for updating multiple sections and it's working fine for me.

Comment: ok but why reloading one section asks the datasource for number of rows in all sections? like [self.tblView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:10] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; is calling numberOFRows in Section method 56 times.

Comment: It may have that you have that much rows in your section.

Comment: is it normal if i reload just one section and it calls numberOfRowsInSection method for all the sections?

Comment: for particular section it should call.if you are changing anything else then it will call otherwise for particular section only.

Comment: no it will call numberOfRowsInSection for all the sections,check the accepted answer. your answer helped too, the second part of my question:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29239/discussion-between-nirav-and-ivishal)